# Can't get submit_tag name in params (rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-submit

I'm trying to build a "two-submit-buttons" edit form that lead to the edit action.

I want to execute two different queries based on the button clicked by the user, but I'm not able to get the submit_tag name in my controller.

In my View

```
<%= form_tag("/points/update", :remote => true, :id => "edit_point_form", :method => :put) do %>
...
   <%= submit_tag "Update all", :name => "submit_all" %>
   <%= submit_tag "Update this point", :name => "submit_this" %>
...
```

In my controller :

```
 def update
    logger.debug params.inspect
    ...
```

gives the following :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", 
 "authenticity_token"=>"w4RserYUA+NWpnWWamTd9dPy/0DDEDU9LRHQ3g25NFk=", 
 "word"=>{"4"=>"T531", "3"=>"", "1"=>"Test 531"},
 "point"=>{"id"=>"106", "group_id"=>"22"}, 
 "action"=>"update", 
 "controller"=>"points", 
 "id"=>"update" }
```

where all these fields are the fields in the form but I can't get the submit_tag name in it. What am I missing ?

Comment: did you sort this out? I am having the same problem

Comment: if you remove: true you will get it in your params hash